# New external hard drive is empty

Tags: hard-drive

I have a NTFS hard drive, which should come with some Windows programs for backups on it. When I mount it, the drive is empty, but 250 Mb is used. I wanted to copy these programs before formatting the drive. Do I need a Windows system to be able to do this? Will I not accidentally overwrite them if I start copying files?

Comment: Normally the programs should just be visible and accessible using Ubuntu.  Have you tried plugging it into a Windows machine?

Comment: I don't have one, but I can try to find one tomorrow.

Comment: You can see what partitions the disk has with the `sudo parted --list` command.

Comment: did you check for the hidden files?

Comment: These files are on a hidden/recovery partition and are not marked as a mountable partition. You need windows to use that software. And yes you can delete that partition from gparted or leave it as is and it will not be deleted.

Comment: I can see this software from Ubuntu now.  The folder with this software gets mounted on one of my **internal** hard drive partitions! That's insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like questions without answers, so add this as an answer. The folder with the software gets mounted on one of my internal hard drive partitions, and shows up among the other files on this partition. I think it is a very strange, but maybe it will happen to someone else too.